# Text outputs as multiple separate lines instead of one paragraph with linebreaks

Tags: ruby, multiline

I have a bot that writes my message to a webpage. I want the message to be sent as one paragraph, but with the lines separated by a linebreak. However, when I actually run the code, the bot inputs and enters each line separately, instead of as one paragraph

I've tried messing with the linebreak formatting and string formatting, but the issue persists

```
reply_messages = []
reply_messages.push([
  "FREE BABY AVOCUDDLE - Thank you for your patience!",
  "To redeem your FREE avocuddle, just use the LINK IN OUR BIO and ADD TO CART - just cover shipping, no additional charges!",
  "Discount AUTOMATICALLY APPLIES! Super simple, no code!",
  "If you order another avocuddle in addition, we cover shipping PLUS the free baby avocuddle! :)",
  "Feel free to DM us if you need anything!"
].join("\n")+"\n")
.
.
.
while true
  browser.get 'https://twitter.com/messages/requests'
  sleep 5
  request = wait.until {
    el = browser.find_element(:css, "[data-testid='conversation']")
    el if el.displayed?
  }
  break if request.nil?

  request.click
  not_acceptable_link = true
  na_link_index = 1
  while not_acceptable_link == true
    accept_btn = browser.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
    unless accept_btn.displayed?
      request_2 = wait.until {
        el = browser.find_elements(:css, "[data-testid='conversation']")[na_link_index]
        el if el.displayed?
      }
      request_2.click
    else
      not_acceptable_link = false
    end
    na_link_index += 1
  end
  accept_btn = browser.find_element(:xpath, "//*[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
  accept_btn.click
  sleep 1
  reply_input = wait.until {
    el = browser.find_element(:css, "[data-testid='dmComposerTextInput']")
    el if el.displayed?
  }
  reply_input.click
  reply_input.send_keys(reply_messages)
.
.
.
```

I would like for the code to output the entire text as one block of text. However, instead, it outputs as separate lines.

Output currently looks like:

```
FREE BABY AVOCUDDLE - Thank you for your patience! 
(enters this into text box)
To redeem your FREE avocuddle, just use the LINK IN OUR BIO and ADD TO CART - just cover shipping, no additional charges!
(enters this into text box)
etc.
```

Instead I would like for it to send as one message.

Comment: Can you share an example of how you would like the result to look, versus how it looks? I'm not really sure what you mean "it outputs as separate lines", because you clearly have newlines in the string

Comment: Added this to my original post. But essentially instead of sending my text as one large paragraph, it will enter one line, submit that, enter the next line, submit that, etc. I want it to send as one large paragraph message.

Comment: I don't have experience with bots, or ruby, but it looks like you're pushing an array of strings. Try joining all the lines and send a single string.

Comment: @Vic they are joining the array with newlines to make it a single string

Comment: Yeah as far as I can tell it is already one string.